# Driver recognization with ubuntu that windows 10 does not recognize

Tags: drivers, sound, graphics

I have a question about going from windows 10 to Ubuntu, except there is a catch. I have  2 drivers on my computer that windows 10 doesn't recognize and so there for says it has an error. dell, the name of my computer company, also wants money for them to fix it as it is a problem of such magnitude that it requires complex programming. the drivers are my intel graphics 4000 driver and my realtec high definition audio driver. Would switching to any Linux platform give me the ability to use those drivers even though windows 10 cannot recognize them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES, ubuntu natively supports both those hardware. So yea you won't have any problems in using them in ubuntu.

Comment: even if windows 10 finds an error when it tries to update either one of those drivers?

Comment: Yups, Windows just have too much bloated driver problems, its much simpler in linux.